# Symfony2.0 Login ,The presented password is invalid

Tags: forms, authentication, symfony

i not understand why return to me always "The presented password is invalid."
i endecoder in sha512

```
security:
    encoders:
        Acme\ProgettoBundle\Entity\User: sha512
```

Comment: Can you share your User Entity and routing.yml code ?

Answer (score 2):

I kept running into this as well. Make sure in your User entity that the password field generated for your user table in the db is large enough to hold the encode/encrypted password value. If it's not, the persist() method will silently truncate the password value to the size of the field.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
 private $password;
```

Comment: You rock - I would of totally missed that for days!

Answer (score 0):

This response is correct: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10452621/2400373 but only is necessary **length:60** for `bcrypt`